# How to exclude subdomain from htaccess changes

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, cloudflare

I have this site lets say (mydomain.com) that has been running for quite a while, we decided that we would like to build a blog too, naturally we wanted to use wordpress(great for blogs). We wanted to use a subdomain blog.mydomain.com

mydomain.com uses cloudflare and the site itself is build with Laravel, our project is placed in public_html/coolproject because of laravel we had to make these changes to our htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ coolproject/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

After deciding to create a blog we naturally created A record in cloudflare pointing to our ip just like the main domain. (blog.mydomain.com)

The issue is following: every time we try to access blog.mydomain.com it shows mydomain.com content.

I think that the issue lies in

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ coolproject/public/$1 [L]
```

because every request is pointed to coolproject/public folder.

I am not very good with htaccess and don't know all of it's possibilities, I am wondering if it's possible to edit this rule so subdomains wouldn't be affected in this scenario and how.

goal is for blog.mydomain.com to show public_html/mycoolblog contents.

Comment: That is not a question about .htaccess it is more a question about your apache configuration where it needs to have a different setup, from your question it sounds like it is going to the same server?

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like the web server on your end not routing this into the correct directory to begin with. Your WP installation should be outside of your Laravel system, I don’t think you should mix the two, that would likely be asking for trouble. So set up a proper VirtualHost for blog.mydomain.com and have it point into the appropriate directory.

Comment: @04FS Laravel project is in public_html/coolproject and wp installation is in public_html/mycoolblog
Not mixing them. 
If i remove all htaccess changes blog.mydomain.com works as it should it points to public_html/mycoolblog

Comment: @KasperFranz If i remove all htaccess changes i made so it would point to laravel project "public" folder, blog.mydomain.com points to the correct folder it's supposed to point "public_html/mycoolblog".

Comment: So both domains point into into `public_html` from the central server configuration, and you only do “local” rewrites in .htaccess further down into the project-specific subfolders from there then? If you want to do this in .htaccess, you need to check the host name send with the request, to figure out which domain it was for. But again, a proper setup would rather be to create separate virtual hosts …

Comment: @04FS Alrighty, I will try to set up separate vh.

Comment: @04FS I think it's only possible if you have full access to your server right? We are on a shared webhost, with a dedicated ip. 
I stand corrected when i said that removing changes in htaccess fixed the issue, it just throws an error now if i do remove all htaccess changes.

I think it's cloudflare and I am doing something wrong with it. We run another domain which works fine with subdomains etc.. on the same webhost only difference is we have not set up cloudflare for it.